# Wallpaper is blurry when cropped from downloaded image

Tags: photos

When creating my own wallpapers on my Nexus S, they always end up being low quality. The image is slightly blurry. Edges are not crisp. These are the steps I'm doing:

1. Download a very large image from the web browser.
2. Long tap my current wallpaper.
3. Wallpapers > Gallery > download
4. Selected the large image and expanded the crop marks to the max.
5. Save

It seems like Android is compressing the image too much. Is there any way to set the quality higher?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try another image editing application?  I mainly use [PhotoWonder](https://market.android.com/details?id=cn.jingling.motu.photowonder), but there's also [Photoshop Express](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.adobe.psmobile).  Both have their issues, but I haven't noticed low quality results with them.  The Nexus S wallpaper size is 960 x 800, so you can make them that size and then use them without having the Nexus S editor do any cropping.